# ExoPlayer doesn work on some devices

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to implement video player (ExoPlayer) in my android app. Player must play video (not big, ~2-3 minutes) from some url. On nexus 5 it works well, but on phone "Samsung GT-I8552 Galaxy Win" unfortunately it doesnt work. There are exception logs after compiling and starting app:

Internal runtime error.
                                                                                                                                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException

at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)

And this is my code:

```
      private SurfaceView surfaceView;
      private ExoPlayer player;
      private MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer videoRenderer;
      private MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer;
      private CustomMediaController mediaController;
      private String userAgent;
      private final int RENDERER_COUNT = 8;
      private static final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
      private static final int BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT =  256;  
      private static final int minBufferMs = 10000;
      private static final int minRebufferMs = 5000;
      private final String videoUrl_2 = "someurl...";
```

...

```
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT, minBufferMs, minRebufferMs);
    userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "MyPlayer");
    Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
    DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, null, userAgent);

    ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(Uri.parse(videoUrl_2), dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
    videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(context,
            sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
    audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);
    player.prepare(videoRenderer, audioRenderer);
    player.sendMessage(videoRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    CustomMediaPlayerControl customMediaPlayerControl = new CustomMediaPlayerControl(player);
    mediaController = new CustomMediaController(context);
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(customMediaPlayerControl);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(surfaceView);
    mediaController.setEnabled(true);
```

My class CustomMediaPlayerControl:

```
public class CustomMediaPlayerControl implements MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {
private ExoPlayer player;

public CustomMediaPlayerControl(ExoPlayer player) {
    this.player = player;
}

@Override
public void start() {
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return (int) player.getDuration();
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return (int) player.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {
    player.seekTo(pos);
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return player.getPlayWhenReady();
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return (int) player.getBufferedPercentage();
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}
}
```

And my class CustomMediaController:

```
public class CustomMediaController extends MediaController {

private MediaController.MediaPlayerControl playerControl;

public CustomMediaController(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void setMediaPlayer(MediaController.MediaPlayerControl playerControl) {
    super.setMediaPlayer(playerControl);
    this.playerControl = playerControl;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    if (playerControl.canSeekForward() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            playerControl.seekTo(playerControl.getCurrentPosition() + 15000); // milliseconds
            show();
        }
        return true;
    } else if (playerControl.canSeekBackward() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            playerControl.seekTo(playerControl.getCurrentPosition() - 5000); // milliseconds
            show();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExoPlayer have a minimal sdk level 16 requirement.

> ExoPlayer’s standard audio and video components rely on Android’s MediaCodec API, which was released in Android 4.1 (API level 16). Hence they do not work on earlier versions of Android.
>   *From: [https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html_)*